# Demonstration with Or elimination

Tags: logic

I'm trying prove this statement

$$(P \wedge Q) \vee (P \wedge R) \vdash P \wedge (Q \vee R)$$

And then :

$$\frac{\frac{(P \wedge Q) \vee (P\wedge R) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{P \wedge Q}{P}(\wedge el)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{P \wedge R}{P}(\wedge el)}{P}(\vee e)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{\frac{(P \wedge Q) \vee ( P \wedge R) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,P \wedge R \,\,\,\,\,\ P\wedge R}{\frac{P \wedge R}{R}(\wedge er)}(\vee e)}{Q\vee R}(\vee ir)}{P \wedge (Q \vee R)}(\wedge i)$$

But at this point  $$\frac{P \wedge R}{R}(\wedge er)$$ 
I cannot proceed. There are another way of doing this?

Comment: Truth tables are another way of proving such things. What kinds of methods of proof have you been told so far?

Comment: Well,I'm trying do that just by Natural Deduction. Truth tables in this case maybe works,but I must understand the process of proofs by Natural Deduction. In bigger proofs,I cannot use truth tables;It's so much slow and costly.
I would like know if exists another way of beginning this type of proof,because my way doesn't seems right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left branch is :

> $(P∧Q)∨(P∧R) \vdash P$

which is Ok.

For the right branch, starting from :

> *i)* $(P∧Q)∨(P∧R)$

you have again to use ($\lor$e) to "unpack" it :

*ii)* $(P∧Q)$ --- assumed

*iii)* $Q$ --- by ($\land$e)

*iv)* $(Q \lor R)$ --- by ($\lor$i)

*v)* $(P∧R)$ --- assumed

*vi)* $R$ --- by ($\land$e)

*vii)* $(Q \lor R)$ --- by ($\lor$i)

Now, from i), with ii) and v) we conclude with : $(Q \lor R)$ by ($\lor$e), discharging the assumptions ii) and v).

In this way, the right branch is :

> $(P∧Q)∨(P∧R) \vdash (Q \lor R)$.

Now you can "merge" left and right branches :

> > $$\frac {(P∧Q)∨(P∧R) \vdash P \quad \quad (P∧Q)∨(P∧R) \vdash (Q \lor R)}{(P∧Q)∨(P∧R) \vdash P \land (Q \lor R)}(\land i)$$

Answer (score 1):

Try having three assumptions... 1. [(P∧Q)∨(P∧R)] 2. (P∧Q), and 3. (P∧R).  Show that  (P∧Q) leads to (P∧(Q∨R)) and that (P∧R) leads to (P∧(Q∨R)).  Then use $\lor$ elimination to get to [(P∧Q)∨(P∧R)].

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right track: your deduction of $P$ is ok, you just need to apply $\vee E$ once again to derive $Q \vee R$:

> 1. $P \wedge Q$, H
> 2. $Q$, 1 $\wedge E$
> 3. $Q \vee R$, 2 $\vee E$
> 4. $(P \wedge Q) \rightarrow (Q \vee R)$, 3 $\rightarrow I$
> 5. //*same for $P \wedge R$
> 6. $((P \wedge Q) \vee (P\wedge R)) \rightarrow (Q \vee R)$ 1-6 $\vee I$
> 7. $Q \vee R$, P, 6 $\rightarrow E$

Comment: @Mauro Edited. Thanks!